# application.css asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm on Rails 3.2.8 and I want to switch to using the asset pipeline.

I am on my dev machine, and have my assets set up like this:
`app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`:

```
  ...    
  *= require_directory ../public/javascripts/jquery/themes/base
  *= require_directory ../public/prototype/stylesheets/css
*/
```

All my stylesheets and js and images are in the public folder which is a catch-all for now. The folder structure:

```
app/assets
  /stylesheets
    /application.css
  /javascripts
  /images
  /public
    /stylesheets
    /javascripts
    /prototype
    /images
```

Currently the `public/assets/application.css` file is empty. How do I compile this file in the development environment?

When I run `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` in rails console, I'm getting `app/assets/public` and not the full directory path for the assets.

In the views, I call the asset pipeline stylesheets: 
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application.css' %>`

EDIT 1:
I tried moving all the stylesheets to `app/assets/stylesheets/` but it is not compiling the application.css properly in the view. It compiles to this:

`<link href="/assets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

And when I view the link, localhost:3000/assets/application.css it is a blank file.

EDIT 2:
I used single quotes instead of double quotes and that fixed the syntax errors. I think I have a handle on it now that I've figured out the pathing. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just leave the original settings of the application.css and let the asset pipeline do the job:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

And in your layout you should be able to load the compiled application.css file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

I disagree with Tam's answer. You shouldn't have to put your files anywhere other then the default locations in development. You can easily mess up your stuff, and unless you need requireJS-like assets management, you can benefit a lot from the asset pipeline.

Here is everything you need to know about the asset pipeline:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Thanks. Your reply helped me figure out my newbie mistake and gave me insight into asset maintenance.

Comment: Oh great! I am glad that I could help :)

Comment: I dissagree what if you want to keep your css files and html javascript in a component based structure?

Answer (score 0):

Move your CSS files to the

```
 app/assets/
```

and just required them from there.

Comment: Oops, I have a typo in my file structure. it's app/assets/public, not app/public. I tested this further by adding the files into app/assets/stylesheets/ but it's still not showing up properly in 0.0.0.0:3000/?debug_assets=1